# Ckeditor 4 with CKfinder 3 strange image source

Tags: ckeditor4.x, ckfinder

I'm trying to integrate CKFinder 3 for .NET with CKeditor 4.5.8 in a dot.net mvc cms application.
All is fine exept the image source, when I insert an image in the editor, instead of a local path the editor inserts an image source like this one below:

src="http://localhost:34997/ckfinder/connector?command=Proxy&lang=en&type=Files&currentFolder=%2F&hash=c245c263ce0eced480effe66bbede6b4d46c15ae&fileName=test-image.jpg"

I have setup the ckeditor configuration like this:
config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html';
config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images';
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/ckfinder/connector?command=QuickUpload&type=Files&currentFolder=/archive/';
config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '/ckfinder/connector?command=QuickUpload&type=Images&currentFolder=/files/';

What may be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

OK the issue have resolved, it needs to add useProxyCommand="false" in the backend section in web.config.